# Calling a 3rd party API returning null value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I have a Laravel 9 project where i'am calling a 3rd party API where im expecting some user information in the returned api response.
Locally the API is working fine and returning all the user info from the 3rd party. Once i pushed the project to a live ubuntu server it was working fine until now it no longer return anything in the json responce.

```
$response = Http::post('https://***.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', $credentials)->object();
```

When i dd($response) on the live server it returns a null value but if i test it locally or on postman the API is working fine.

Comment: before returning object check status and errors if any

Comment: status is 200 that's what's weired @JohnLobo

Comment: generate the php curl code from the postman and check if that works. and if it adds any different type of headers like `content-type`, I had this type of issue due to it and had to use the `asForm()` method for submission.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my servers IP was blocked by the 3rd party app that i was calling it's API.